# Regex: Add html tags at the lines that doesn't have html tags at the beginning and end of it

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I have this paragraph. Also, I have a line `I need someone to take me home.` that doesn't have html tags. So, I need to find this line (not others) and frame it between tags

```
<!-- START -->

<p class="mb-40px">I may go to cinema</p>

I need someone to take me home.

<p class="mb-40px">I can love you now</p>

<!-- FINAL -->
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<!-- START -->

<p class="mb-40px">I may go to cinema</p>

<p class="mb-40px">I need someone to take me home.</p>

<p class="mb-40px">I can love you now</p>

<!-- FINAL -->
```

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe someone will need a solution of this kind of problem:**

Use the following:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?!<p class="mb-40px">)(([a-zA-Z-].+))((?!</p>).)*$`
- Replace with: `<p class="mb-40px">\2</p>`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>